# Can't able to change powerpoint slide show window height c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have attached a powerpoint presentation slideshow in Visual studio panel. I want to change my slideshowwindow height and width dynamically. so i have assigned value 0 to both left and top properties. But it is not taking this values. It is throwing some randow values every time.

```
PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings sst = null;

PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow sw=null;

sst = presentation.SlideShowSettings;

sw = sst.Run();

sw.Left = 0;
sw.Top = 0;
```

What i am doing wrong...

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i reset the parent of slideshow, than again i have used setparent.

SetParent(pptptr, (IntPtr)null);

SetParent(pptptr, panel11.Handle);

now it is working fine